# How to save / access audio file, sent by Skype?

Tags: windows, skype

I got MP3 file sent

[image]

Unfortunately, I can only play it withing Skype. I can't find it in `%appdata%/Skype/My Skype Received Files` neither I can save it with Skype context menu or drag-n-drop.

Is it possible to access this file?

Skype version is unknown (don't know how to see), it is latest Desktop, updated in recent month (July 2018)

Comment: Have you try with right click?

Answer (score 0):

I made a test in my skype, I can save and access the video file. I only download the video file, and find it in the following path:

[image]

To save or access audio file sent by Skype:

Firstly, I suggest we use the latest skype version, we can view the version by two ways:

1.Click on the "Help" item in the SKYPE drop-down menu, then open "About SKYPE", then an interface will pop up and you will see the version of SKYPE you are using.

2.Right click the "Skype", select "App  settings", we will see the version.
The skype version of mine is 12.1815.210.0 as below.

[image]

If it does not work, we can open chat in web.skype.com and use developer tools we can download it from network tab. The solution is in the original post that the author has updated.

For the details we can refer the articles: [How to save audio message as a file?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_mac-skype_messms-skype_instamessms/how-to-save-audio-message-as-a-file/00db2fd1-26fc-4565-8dd0-53840a38ea15)

In addition, I find two tools we can try, how to use them we can refer the two articles:

TalkHelper: [How to save/download Skype voicemails/Voice messages to MP3 File?](http://www.talkhelper.com/FAQ/save-Skype-voicemail.html)

Actual File Folders utility: [How to find a folder to which Skype saves received files and open it in 2 clicks](https://www.actualtools.com/articles/detail.php?ID=1435)

Comment: It works for video but not for audio

Comment: Do you try the three ways in the links?

Answer (score 0):

My Skype download folder is

```
This PC > Downloads > Skype > All
```

[image]

Skype Version is [image]